# In Slim templates, HTML comments on separate lines are rendered on the same line

Tags: ruby, templates, slim-lang

When writing HTML comments in SLIM:

```
/! The first line of comments
/! The second line of comments
```

The output becomes

```
<!-- The first line of comments --><!-- The second line of comments -->
```

All the other generated HTML is properly formatted and indented because I set `pretty` equal to `true`

I'm writing templates for other people to use so I need comments with line breaks for readability.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve a single multi-line comment in Slim like this:

```
/!
  The first line of comments
  The second line of comments
```

Which should output this:

```
<!-- The first line of comments
The second line of comments -->
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. The result is the same as in my original post.

Comment: Sorry! You don't need the `|`  I made the edit in the post (... and I actually tested it this time!)

Comment: I tried exactly that and in the HTML I see a single line: "<!--The first line of comments The second line of comments-->"

Any ideas how to force it to be on 2 lines?